# Fahrenheit to Celsius using multiple methods

Tags: java

I'm supposed to make a program that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius and Celsius to Fahrenheit. I'm also supposed to prompt for input using input class methods, and my program is supposed to have multiple methods. So far, this is what I've come up with:

```
public class FahrenheitoCelsius

{

   public static double conversion_fahrenheit_to_celsius()
      {
          if(( F >= 0 ) | ( F< 0))   
          {
          System.out.println(" The temperature is (Celsius_to_Fahrenheit( y ) ) degrees. " );
          }
          else
          {
          System.out.println(" The temperature is (Fahrenheit_to_Celsius( x ) ) degrees. " );

          }
      }




    public static double Fahrenheit_degrees( double F )
      {
         double F = 32; 
      }
   public static void Celsius_degrees( double C )
     {
         double C = 0;
     }


  public static double Fahrenheit_to_Celsius( double x )
     {
        x = 5/9 * ((Fahrenheit_degrees( F )) - 32);
     }
   public static double  Celsius_to_Fahrenheit( double y)
      {
        y = ( 9/5 * (Celsius_degrees( C ))) + 32; 
      }

}
```

I'm also supposed to use some of the following:

```
import javax.swing.*;


public class Input
{
    public static byte getByte( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Byte.parseByte( input );
    }

    public static short getShort( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Short.parseShort( input );
    }

    public static int getInt( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Integer.parseInt( input );
    }

    public static long getLong( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Long.parseLong( input );
    }

    public static float getFloat( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Float.parseFloat( input );
    }

    public static double getDouble( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Double.parseDouble( input );
    }

    public static boolean getBoolean( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return Boolean.parseBoolean( input );
    }

    public static char getChar( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return input.charAt(0);
    }

    public static String getString( String s )
    {
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( s );
        return input;
    }

}
```

How do I incorporate those into my program? 
Note: I'm not sure if my program that I've come up with so far is even correct; any feedback would be appreciated since I'm new to Java.

Comment: You need to learn coding java, that's what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

First thing what I notice is that method "conversion_fahrenheit_to_celsius" in conversion class isn't correct. It always gives you back those strings what you have in print-lines. Also you need inputs in your method, cause methods what you use need inputs (temperature).

So correct method is:

```
public static double conversion_fahrenheit_to_celsius(double y, double x)
      {
          if(( F >= 0 ) | ( F< 0))   
          {
          System.out.println(" The temperature is " + Celsius_to_Fahrenheit( y ) + " degrees. " );
          }
          else
          {
          System.out.println(" The temperature is " + Fahrenheit_to_Celsius( x ) " degrees. " );

          }
      }
```

You need to use input class in main method, like user ljgw showed.

I recommend to you to watch some tutorials and then you see how to write Java. One choice is TheNewBoston - Java (Beginner) Programming Tutorials https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28

Answer (score 0):

There are several things 'wrong' with your program, but you need to find and fix those yourself. I will however provide you with a starting point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String choice = Input.getString("Do you want to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius (type 'F') or from Celsius to Fahrenheit (type 'C')");
    if ("c".equalsIgnoreCase(choice)){
        //celsius --> fahrenheit code
    } else {
        //fahrenheit --> celsius code
    }
}
```